# REST returns Vaadin's HTML instead of String

Tags: java, rest, vaadin

I'm trying to integrate REST into my Vaadin 8 app. I'm getting Vaadin HTML as a response from my client request instead of a String. I use `jetty:run` via Maven. What is the issue?

**Client:**

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/api/rest/hello");
        Response response = target.request().get();
        String value = response.readEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println("Response: " + value);
```

**UI Class:**

```
 @WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/api/*", "/VAADIN/*"}, asyncSupported = true)
        @VaadinServletConfiguration(closeIdleSessions = true, ui = ApiUI.class, productionMode = false)
        public static class ApiUIServlet extends VaadinServlet { ...
```

Stackoverflow won't let me post more code. Here are the additional classes: https://pastebin.com/4i3MFXEZ

Comment: Here `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/api/*", "/VAADIN/*"}, asyncSupported = true)` it looks like you're configuring the VaadinServlet to the URL `/api/*`, which would mean the Vaadin servlet will take over all requests coming to localhost:8080/api, whether they come from a browser or a REST request. Instead, you should configure the VaadinServlet to e.g. `/ui/*`  and use `/api/*` for the REST requests.

Comment: @ollitietavainen thanks for the reply. So should my code be this? `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/ui/*", "/api/*"}, asyncSupported = true)`

Comment: No, you should have the "/ui/*" and "/VAADIN/*" url patterns only on your VaadinServlet. "/api/*"  should NOT be handled by the VaadinServlet, VaadinServlet should only serve the Vaadin UI. Let another non-Vaadin servlet handle "/api/*"

Comment: @ollitietavainen thank you! I took some time to figure this out myself with your guidance. I used an httpservlet and `doPost` method in order to handle my api now.  One question though, if I want different api endpoints for different `POST` calls, do I use separate servlets for each? Like `@WebServlet("/api/p1")` and  `@WebServlet("/api/p2")`? Thanks again.

Comment: I think you can have a single "REST API" servlet with different URL mappings to different endpoints. Versioning the endpoints is a good idea; take a look at https://vaadin.com/blog/making-rest-apis-for-vaadin-applications